# Giving LinearGradient Shade From Bottom of the TextView in Android

Tags: android, css, android-layout

[image]

[image]

```
TextView secondTextView = new TextView(this);
    Shader textShader=new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 20,
            new int[]{Color.GREEN,Color.BLUE},
            new float[]{0, 1}, TileMode.CLAMP);
    secondTextView.getPaint().setShader(textShader);
```

The above particular code giving me green shade at the top and blue as text color but my requirement is absolutely in reverse order all i need is green color shade from the bottom and blue as text color. can someone please help me out to achieve this.

Comment: you can add gradient directly through drawable folder.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.timuzsolutions.cakejam where the description last line is half visible in google play store, i need exactly the same effect.

Comment: Add a pic of your requirement.

Comment: exactly the description style which google play store app uses for showing the apps description

Comment: @ Dhinakaran i want the above gradient effect from the bottom.

Comment: @Vijayalaxmi Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you.

```
Shader myShader = new LinearGradient(
            0, 0, 0, 100,
            Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK,
            Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    secondTextView.getPaint().setShader(myShader);
```

[image]

Comment: @Vijayalaxmi see the image

Comment: @Vijayalaxmi you need black and white shade??

Comment: Yes, assume if my textview contains 5 lines only the 5th line should have slightly faded effect. to be more clear please check the description style which google play android app uses to show all the apps description.

Comment: @Vijayalaxmi see the answer... and text is dynamically setting??

Comment: @ hitesh hope the second image will make u more clear, i need the white color fading from the bottom that to only for last line